# ServiceBusTrigger process Deadletter message

Tags: azure, servicebus

I have a current topic queue which send some messages to deadletter queue.  I am creating another Webjob which listen to ServiceBusTrigger on the deadletter queue. The purpose is to resubmit the deadletter mesg to original queue to be re-processed

When a new message comes to the deadletter queue, I would clone the message and send it back to the original topic subscription to re-process.

I expect that the clone message would be sent to the original queue and stay there until it is processed, but turn out the message is completed as soon as the [originalTopicClient.Send(cloneMessage);] function called.

Am I missing anything?

```
public void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger(topicName, dlqSubscription)] string message, TextWriter log)
   {
        MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.Create(ServiceURI, tokenProvider);

            string deadLetterQueuePath = SubscriptionClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(topicName, SubscriptionName);

            SubscriptionClient dlqSubscriptionClient = factory.CreateSubscriptionClient(topicName, "mytopicsubscription/$DeadLetterQueue");
            QueueClient deadletterQueueClient = factory.CreateQueueClient(deadLetterQueuePath);
            BrokeredMessage cloneMessage;
            Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient originalTopicClient = Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(serviceBusEndpoint, topicName);

            BrokeredMessage dlqMessage;
            if ((dlqMessage = dlqSubscriptionClient.Receive()) != null)
            {
                cloneMessage = dlqMessage.Clone();
                cloneMessage.Properties.Remove("DeadLetterReason");
                cloneMessage.Properties.Remove("DeadLetterErrorDescription");

                originalTopicClient.Send(cloneMessage); //resend the clone message to original queue


                dlqMessage.Complete(); //deadletter queue mesg completed
            }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if the message you try to clone is not expired? Perhaps you can try to set up its TTL property before sending.

Comment: Hi @Peter, I actually had the TTL in before send the clonemessage.  cloneMessage.TimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and then after quite a long research, I found that it worked perfectly fine in 3 ways.

The first one is to receive the message in `ReceiveAndDelete` mode. This deletes the message from the DLQ and so we can safely send it to the main queue without issues. The second way is to receive the message in `PeekLock` mode, `Complete` the message, and then `Send` it. This is nothing different from the first method except that we are completing rather than the Service Bus client doing it. The third way is to create a new `BrokeredMessage` and copy the necessary payload from the received message and send it as an entirely new message to the main queue.

While the reason for the `Send` to not work in your method is still unknown, I see that the `Clone` and `Send` work fine without `Complete`, and it seems like the clone is still referring to the original message.